# How to recalculate a column to remove blank?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've a table which contains various ranking:

```
id  | rank_group    | position
1   |1              | 2
2   |1              | 3
3   |2              | 1
6   |2              | 2
8   |1              | 8
9   |1              | 6
10  |1              | 7
```

I wonder if it possible to re base/re calculate all position for each rank group with one query in order to make them follow the others?

It means I woulk like the table became:

```
id  | rank_group    | position
1   |1              | 1
2   |1              | 2
3   |2              | 1
6   |2              | 2
8   |1              | 5
9   |1              | 3
10  |1              | 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with the help of a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT [id], [rank_group], [position],
           rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rank_group ORDER BY position ASC)
   FROM dbo.Table1
)
UPDATE CTE SET position = rowNum;
```

[`DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5094a/2/0)

Comment: I reorder them keeping same position order, so I just change your `ORDER BY id ASC` to `ORDER BY position ASC`, thanks !

Comment: @Fractaliste: ok, that makes sense. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward update with count of items of lower position within the same `rank_group` will do the trick:

```
update test
set position = 1 + (
  select count(*) from test tt
  where t.rank_group=tt.rank_group AND tt.position < t.position
)
from test t
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e8b432/1)